# Is it possible to sync Rhythmbox playlist to Ubuntu One Music or use a m3u file as Ubuntu One playlist?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, music, rhythmbox, playlists

I recently started trying Ubuntu One music streaming and now it feels good. However I have a problem here: I used to have several long playlists for myself in Rhythmbox (300-500 songs each playlist, in my favored order), and I really liked to play songs from the playlist instead of shuffling all songs.

**So, I wonder if I can upload my playlist to Ubuntu One music, or make a same playlist on Ubuntu One Music without dragging songs one by one**. Is it possible to do this in Rhythmbox or do it by uploading some m3u playlist file? Or maybe some other method? Please suggest me any method that can "copy" my playlist to Ubuntu One music.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

I have a script which will convert an M3U to an Ubuntu One playlist (and dump an Ubuntu One playlist to an M3U). You can download it at http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~sil/+junk/m3u2u1ms/files. Requires Ubuntu 12.04 or better. Let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thanks sil, I tried your script by type "python m3u2u1ms Music.m3u" in the terminal, and I have the following output: wei@wei-air:~/Downloads$ python m3u2u1ms Music.m3u
Scanning songs
Finding Ubuntu One identifiers for songs
90 songs correctly identified from playlist
Looking for an existing playlist 'Music'...
[{'id': u'01768f89-891a-47c3-a170-fe5e3ff9b8fc', 'name': u'Music'}]
Found an existing playlist: updating it
got result <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<subsonic-response xmlns="http://subsonic.org/restapi"
    status="ok"
    version="1.2.0">
</subsonic-response>

Comment: Could you find any reason the these errors? actually I had different output for different m3u files...and none of them was successfully created. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: It's printing stuff that it shouldn't (I left some debugging statements in, oops); can you check with the web music player to see if it thinks that they're being created?

Comment: Hi sil, the playlist was created, however it was empty (since they had error during the process?).

Comment: Hm, that's obviously not supposed to happen. Does it fail the same way every time?

Comment: I think so sil. Another thing is for different playlist, I got different error report. For example: Scanning songs
Finding Ubuntu One identifiers for songs
Unhandled error in Deferred:
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: ubuntuone.platform.tools.linux.IPCError: org.freedesktop.DBus.Python.KeyError:

Comment: I really have not much idea about programming...I'm also looking for other methods on the internet but until now it was fruitless...

Comment: Sorry, lost track of this conversation. Maybe track me down on IRC and we can debug problems live? I'm aquarius on freenode.